# excel : autocomplete line with data from other sheet

Tags: excel, autofill

I try to link excel sheets together.
Here is my second sheet

```
A 1 2 3
B 4 5 6
C 7 8 9
D 10 11 12
```

When I write in the first sheet

```
C
```

I would like excel to auto fill the whole line like that

```
C 7 8 9
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You might be able to use Excel's data validation for this e.g. with VBA https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html AND without http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/autocomplete-validation.htm

Comment: Yes there a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the VLOOKUP function will do the job.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: if you need more complex answer, feel free to ask me ;)